# How to visualize frequency domain of signal with multiples of $f_s$?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, sampling, frequency, aliasing

Is it possible to visualize signal in frequency domain for frequencies bigger than $f_s$?

I'd like to get the plot of some example signal like that:
[image]

I tried to create some signals in `Python` with different relation of signal frequency and sampling frequency, but I wasn't succeed((

original code:

```
f_sampling = 2e6
f_sig1 = 700e3

t = np.arange(0,50e-3,0.01e-6)
t_sample = np.arange(0, len(t)*1/f_sampling, 1/f_sampling)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

signal_test = np.cos(2*np.pi*f_sig1*t)
f1 = np.cos(2*np.pi*f_sig1*t_sample)

plt.plot(t, signal_test, label='CW')
plt.plot(t_sample, f1, marker='o', label='digitized')

plt.xlim(0, 50e-6)
plt.legend(loc='lower center')
```

adding 2 zeros between each sample and FFT of it:

```
zero_data = []

for i in f1:
    zero_data.append(i)
    zero_data.append(0)
    zero_data.append(0)

zero_data = np.asarray(zero_data)
    
t_zeros = np.linspace(0,len(zero_data)*t_sample[1], len(zero_data))

FFT = np.fft.fft(zero_data*3)
freqs_fft = np.fft.fftfreq(len(zero_data*3), t_zeros[1])
```

which outputs:

[image]

here I didn't get frequencies above $f_s$

And another question - why do we have $f_s$ of signal in frequency domain?

Comment: Do you know what aliasing is ?

Comment: @Hilmar, yes. But I have no idea, how sampling frequency occurs in frequency domain and is it possible to visualize it in `Python` for example.

Comment: @Curious if you know what aliasing is, then you already know what the spectrum outside the nyquist bandwidth looks like, so what's the question?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I don't exactly get, why do I see $f_s$ in the spectrum? in the explanation of aliasing this fact (the presence of $f_s$) is assumed as it is without explanation.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. you don't need to know $f_s$ to make a plot *relative* to $f_s$. Exactly as the plot you show!

Comment: @MarcusMüller, my first question - why do I see $f_s$ in the spectrum (while the original signal has only one frequency not equal to $f_s$); and another question - how to plot it for tests (in `Python`, `Matlab` etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To visualize the frequencies of discrete time signals beyond the sampling rate, simply insert $M-1$ zeros in between each sample and scale the signal by $M$. This will extend the frequency axis by $M$ where $M$ is any positive integer. What you will see is the periodicity in the frequency domain as given for discrete time signals.

Comment: Thank you for advice! But in this case the signal will not be the same or what do you mean?

Comment: The signal will be exactly the same in the frequency domain. You will see all the aliasing that results- if you filter out those aliases you will have completed interpolation and then the signal will also be exactly the same in the time domain.

Comment: ok, for example, I'll insert 2 zeros at sampling distance between each sample and what do you mean next - scaling the signal by $M$?

Comment: Multiply all samples by 3- in this case you give M=3

Comment: why should I do so?

Comment: You do that if you want the fft to have the same scale as you did originally. Overall the zero insert is the discrete time equivalent of convolving with an impulse response and that is why it doesn’t change the frequency domain signal but reveals the images. (I should have said filter out the images not aliases above)

Comment: I tried to insert 2 zeros between each sample and multiplied all samples by factor of 3, but I still have only one frequency (positive and negative) and zero component also added (and nothing more, I didn't get frequencies higher or multiple of $f_s$), I use `np.fft.fftfreq` for calculating frequencies

Comment: Please post your example code in your question and confirm yourself that the upsampled sequence is x0 0 0 x1 0 0 x2 ….

Comment: please see the code, I added it.

Comment: Looks right! Your horizontal axis now represents frequencies to 3fs

Comment: sorry, I've pasted incorrect picture of FFT, but now it is correct; nevertheless, I didn' get frequecnies bigger than $f_s$... no replicas of $f_s$ in the spectrum

Comment: adding zeros between each sample changed the frequency spectrum (actual signal frequency is 700 kHz, but spectrum shows something around 25 kHz, 50 kHz and 100 kHz).

Comment: After you add the zeros, your sampling rate is 3x so your frequency axis as you show should extend to 3MHz— you need to fix that and then it should make sense.

Comment: ah, sure, I didn't multiply frequencies by factor of 3; ok, now I clearly see components of $f_s$+$f_{signal}$ and $f_s$-$f_{signal}$, is it correct?

Comment: Yes it looks correct to me- you see components at each multiple of the original sample rate. Did I answer your original question correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132680/discussion-between-dan-boschen-and-curious).

Comment: left few questions in chat)

Comment: and another one)